# What does "test" mean in System Status of Spring Eureka

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka

My Spring Eureka instance always shows test in the Environment field at System Status Panel. What does "test" mean?

[image]

I didn't find none about this in the documentation of Spring Eureka.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to logging purpose,
you can change it

```
eureka:
  environment: Development
```